# Magento 1.9.1.1 404 pages on store view

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, store, multilingual

I've got this Magento setup that's supposed to be working as a multilanguage store. Basically I've got 3 different languages and let's say, for example, that I got the 'Terms and Conditions' page. Now, on one of the languages the url is '/termeni-si-conditii' and on the second language the url looks like '/terms-and-conditions'. If someone lands from a search engine on '/terms-and-conditions' the default language is the first one and this particular page shows as a 404 one. However if I change the language the same url shows the actual content on this page. No more 404's.

Is there a way to set the appropriate the language based on the landing url? So if they land on '/terms-and-conditions' show the content here, rather than showing the 404.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent this is to make a URL Rewrite redirect in

```
Catalog >> URL Rewrite management
```

There you can add 301 redirects per specific store view. So for Italian store view add redirect from `/terms-and-conditions` to `/termeni-si-conditioni`. Follow the same logic for English store view.

Comment: Thanks mate, I did end up doing this, even though I reckon there should be an easier way of sorting this one out. Cheers!